# How to get dictionary and how to break from i for i in m if m iteration

Tags: python

Starting with a list variable:

```
number=[1,2,3,None,4,5]
```

I can get the same result taking two different approaches:

Approach 1:

```
result=[number for number in numbers if number]
```

Approach 2:

```
result=[]
for number in numbers:
    if not number: continue
    result.append(number)
```

Approach 2 aside from taking more code to put together appears to be 30% slower to execute.
Since Approach 1 wins in both the speed and clarity department I would like to utilize it more often.

Two questions:

Question 1:

Can I use `[i for i in m if i]` approach to build a dictionary variable?
So if I start with a list variable :

```
number=[1,2,3,None,4,5]
```

how can I get to a dictionary where every list variable number becomes a dictionary key:
such as:

```
result={1:None, 2:None, 3:None, 4:None, 5:None}
```

or even:

```
result={1:{}, 2:{}, 3:{}, 4:{}, 5:{}}
```

Question 2:

Can I `break` from `[i for i in m if i]` iteration if a certain condition met? For example:

```
result=[]
for number in numbers:
    if not number: continue
    if number==5: 
        result.append(number)
        break
```

Apparently I can't put it like this:

```
result=[number for number in numbers if number and number==5 break]
```

And third bonus question: Is the output of  `[i for i in m if i]` iteration always a list? If not please post some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1: you can do:

```
result = {i: None for i in number if i}
```

Or:

```
result = {i: {} for i in number if i}
```

Question 2: you can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) for this:

```
result = [i for i in itertools.takewhile(lambda n: bool(n), number)]
```

Question 3: if you write it like that then yes. But if you write `(i for i in number if i)` then it's not a list. In that case it's a generator expression:

```
>>> t = (i for i in number if i)
>>> t
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x106039dc0>
```

This means you can use it for iteration (`for item in t:`) without constructing the list. You can also convert it back to a list by calling `list(t)`.

Comment: For question 2: Can I break from the iteration returning other than a list variable using itertools.takewhile?

Comment: @Sputnix: probably not, the idea is that the condition depends on the elements in the list.